# Plotting highest high of previous 5min on 1min timeframe

Tags: pine-script

I'm attempting to plot the highest high of the previous 5min bar on a 1min timeframe.

This is my script

```
//@version=4
study("HTFB B/S 2", overlay=true)

start_y = input(2020, "Year")
start_m = input(5, "Month")
start_d = input(22, "Day")

t5 = time("5")

var float hi1 = na
var float hi5 = na

is_newbar_t5 = not na(t5) and (na(t5[1]) or t5 > t5[1])
canrun = time > timestamp(start_y,start_m,start_d,09,30,0)-1 and time < timestamp(start_y,start_m,start_d,10,0,0)+1

if canrun
    hi1 := high
    if is_newbar_t5
        label.new(bar_index, high, "newbar_t5", yloc=yloc.abovebar)
        hi5 := highest(high,5)
else
    hi1 := na
    hi5 := na

plot(hi1, title="hi1")
plot(hi5, title="hi5", color = is_newbar_t5 ? na : color.lime)
```

Which results in this plot (on ticker `SPX`)

[image]

As you can see, this is not the expected outcome, because it does not plot the highest high of the previous 5 minutes.
I don't see why this doesn't work.
The statement `hi5 := highest(high,5)` is supposed to get the highest high of the previous 5 1min bars.
But it doesn't seem to do that.

Is this a bug in Pine Script?
Or more likely, an error in my logic?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the fact that `highest()` is among the functions that require evaluation on every bar to return the correct value, so we need to force this by taking it outside the `if` block.

This will produce the expected behavior:

```
h = highest(high,5)
if canrun
    hi1 := high
    if is_newbar_t5
        label.new(bar_index, high, "newbar_t5", yloc=yloc.abovebar, color=color.orange)
        hi5 := h
else
    hi1 := na
    hi5 := na
```

With the date set to the 28th:
[image]